# How to round the value using in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want round the below way using jquery

if 50 or 55 need to round the 60.
if 70 or 61 need to round 80.

if 131 to 139 need to round 140 .

Please any one help me.

Comment: What have  you tried?

Comment: jQuery has no such function - javascript however can help with `Math.round(n/100) * 100`

Comment: Why do you want to use jQuery to solve your problem? This is a trivial mathematical task in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

Just use JavaScript:

```js
function round(a) {
 return Math.round(a / 100) * 100
}
console.log(round(50), round(60), round(160), round(180));
```

Answer (score 1):

131 goes to 140 and, 51 to 60 as you mentioned in the question.

```js
console.log(myop(51));
console.log(myop(131));

function myop(val) {
  return (Math.ceil(val / 10) * 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

http://fiddle.jshell.net/8Lyab/37/

```
var f = 60;

var tenth = Math.round(f/100)*100;
alert(tenth)
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need jquery to do this. You can use `Math.ceil()`:

```
Math.ceil(num/ 100.0) * 100;
```